# In Rails, which is a better defender against XSS attacks, strip_tags or sanitize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, xss, sanitization, sanitize

Assuming no tags are allowed in the user input and we want to sanitize user input *before* storing it in the database, in Rails, we have the options of using `sanitize` (whitelist an empty set of tags) and `strip_tags`.

Which is better against XSS attacks?  If something else is even better, what is that? And why is it better?

Comment: Are you using rails 4?  The rails core team did a lot to make things safe by default midway through rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 3 and the fatty beatdown the Rails core dev team took when they made Rails unsafe by default, all strings are now tagged as either safe or unsafe with "unsafe" strings being the default.  You only need to think about explicitly managing the "safeness" of strings in Rails when you're writing helpers that output HTML into your template.

**Escaping vs Sanitizing:**
In this context, escaping means replacing some of the string characters with an HTML escape sequence that will remove the special meaning from the text and cause it render as regular text.  Sanitizing on the other hand, means validating the HTML content to ensure only good HTML tags and attributes are used.  Note that sanitizing is inherently less secure than escaping because of this and should only be used where rendered content must contain HTML markup.  An example would be a WYSIWYG HTML editor on a textarea that manages code that is later rendered on a page.

Sanitize encodes all tags and strips all attributes (not specifically allowed which is all in your case) from the html string passed to it.  It also strips href and src tags with invalid protocols to prevent any abuse of js attributes.  Strip_tags on the other hand will strip all supplied tags including comments which sounds like exactly what you want.  As long as you're whitelisting params and adding them to your DB properly escaped such as:

```
   Title.where(author = ?, author_id)
```

and not blindly inserting user input into your db I would be comfortable with how you're setup.

Comment: Validation is an idempotent process. I guess ‘filtering’ would be a better term for describing the removal of something inadequate.

Comment: A [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) is recommended when outputting "sanitized" user data, such as HTML. This will prevent the browser executing any XSS that an attacker manages to slip through the sanitizer.